# highly optimized algo to sort an array consisting of only 0s n 1s

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I need to find a highly optimized algo to sort an array consisting of only 0s n 1s.

My version of the solution is to count the no. of zeroes(say x) and ones(say y). Once you do that, place x zeroes in the array followed by y 1s. This makes it O(n).

Any algo that runs better than this??? I was asked this question in interview.

Comment: You do have to scan the complete array once. That makes it O(n). I dont think any other algorithm can better O(n).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have to examine each of `n` input elements, you can't improve on `O(n)`.

Also, since your algorithm requires `O(1)` memory, you can't improve on that either (there's nothing asymptotically better than `O(1)`).

Answer (score 7):

we can't do better than O(n), but looks like we can do in one pass

```
low = 0; 
high = arr.length - 1;

while (low < high) {
    while (arr[low] == 0) {
        low ++;
    }
    while (arr[high] == 1) {
        high --;
    }
    if (low < high) {
    //swap arr[low], arr[high]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you sum the array, you could have the number of 1's, slightly more efficient, but still O(n).

Answer (score 3):

You can't be more efficient than O(N) because each item needs to be inspected.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of an "array" are we talking about? If we were to count the bits in a 16-bit unsigned integer then several O(1) time algorithms have been developed: see [Fast Bit Count Routines](http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/).

This is one of the algorithms presented there; the one they call the Nifty Parallel Count:

```c
#define MASK_01010101 (((unsigned int)(-1))/3)
#define MASK_00110011 (((unsigned int)(-1))/5)
#define MASK_00001111 (((unsigned int)(-1))/17)
int bitcount (unsigned int n) {
   n = (n & MASK_01010101) + ((n >> 1) & MASK_01010101);
   n = (n & MASK_00110011) + ((n >> 2) & MASK_00110011);
   n = (n & MASK_00001111) + ((n >> 4) & MASK_00001111);
   return n % 255 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a single-rod abacus sort. 
Now I'm curious who your interviewer was.

http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/abacussort.html